# Not able to update FBSDKCoreKit POD iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am getting the following error when I try to do pod update. once it failed, I am not even able to do pod install anymore.

> Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.36.0)
>
> [!] Error installing FBSDKCoreKit [!] /usr/bin/git clone
>   https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
>   /var/folders/tq/jky5s5j1589c5nqhs3n7j3d00000gn/T/d20180831-29436-tmqja3
>   --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch sdk-version-4.36.0
>
> Cloning into
>   '/var/folders/tq/jky5s5j1589c5nqhs3n7j3d00000gn/T/d20180831-29436-tmqja3'...
>   warning: Could not find remote branch sdk-version-4.36.0 to clone.
>   fatal: Remote branch sdk-version-4.36.0 not found in upstream origin

Comment: Can we all 'Same here!' the bug report on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/242258916492125/?disable_redirect=0

Answer (score 32):

According to the [change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4x), version 4.36.0 was released yesterday (30th August). It looks like they've forgotten to create a release tag for it yet in their Github repository hosting the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases).

In the meantime, you can set your pod to:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.35'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.35'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.35'
```

then pod update.

Comment: What if you are using `pod 'FacebookCore'` etc.?

Comment: Can we all 'Same here!' the bug report on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/242258916492125/?disable_redirect=0

Comment: Facebook really has serious QA problems for sure. I've changed my version to `4.35` and still got the same error. Downgrading back to *4.34* solved my problem.

Comment: for me 4.35 actually worked, but before that I cleaned the POD cache, and did a pod deintegrate, pod update. Try that

Comment: As of today: fixed by FB so no more downgrade of those pods required.

Answer (score 2):

As per Facebook Developer Team, This issue has been resolved in:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases/tag/sdk-version-4.36.0 .

Please update your pods to the latest version and try again.