# Anybody got a workaround for error updating 'FacebookCore' pod with Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cocoapods

When running 'pod update' on a podfile containing:

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

I get the below error in terminal:

> [!] Error installing FBSDKCoreKit [!] /usr/bin/git clone
>   https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
>   /var/folders/vq/_hfk18595y56rhc85mz5jrzr0000gn/T/d20180831-47902-i1qcic
>   --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch sdk-version-4.36.0
>
> Cloning into
>   '/var/folders/vq/_hfk18595y56rhc85mz5jrzr0000gn/T/d20180831-47902-i1qcic'...
>   warning: Could not find remote branch sdk-version-4.36.0 to clone.
>   fatal: Remote branch sdk-version-4.36.0 not found in upstream origin

There is a workaround if using 'FBSDKCoreKit', 'FBSDKLoginKit', 'FBSDKShareKit' here: [Not able to update FBSDKCoreKit POD iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107508/not-able-to-update-fbsdkcorekit-pod-ios)

But does anyone have a workaround when using 'FacebookCore', 'FacebookLogin', 'FacebookShare'?

Comment: FB Bug Report: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/242258916492125/?disable_redirect=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your pod to:

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '0.3.1'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '0.3.1'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.35.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.35.0'
```

then `pod update`.

OBS: I didn't test the `FacebookShare` pod, but I think you can use the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook added the release tag to the Github repository and this issue should now be resolved.